# Dependabot cannot update lodash.template to a non-vulnerable version

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, lodash

I need help to resolve a GitHub vulnerability issue in dependabot. While doing scan in dependbot I get errors:

> gulp-sass-grapher@1.0.0 requires lodash.template@^3.0.0 via gulp-util@3.0.8

> @sxa/celt@10.3.0 requires lodash.template@^3.0.0 via a transitive dependency on gulp-util@3.0.8

> gulp-upload@1.0.0 requires lodash.template@^3.0.0 via gulp-util@3.0.8
> No patched version available for lodash.template

Can you please help me with that how to resolve this error using npm or any other command line.

Above error's package tree is below

```text
@sxa/Theme@1.0.1 C:\hmh\Common
+-- @sxa/celt@10.3.0
| `-- gulp-prompt@1.2.0
|   `-- lodash.template@4.5.0 
+-- gulp-prompt@1.2.0
| `-- lodash.template@4.5.0 
`-- gulp-sass-grapher@1.0.0
  `-- gulp-util@3.0.8
    `-- lodash.template@3.6.2
```

can you please support to fix this vulnerability. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to update all npm libraries by running below command,

> npm update

2. If the above step doesn't works for us, add the "lodash.template" plugin to your package.json file and then try npm install/update
3. Delete node modules and package.lock file and then try npm install again.